# Go to next page until element found

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress for my automated tests. I'm trying to find a product on a page and click on it. If the product not displayed on the page, go to the next one until it is found.
I've been trying a lot of things already: while loop, each loop, simple cy.get but none of them work. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need a recursive command, implementation of which will depend on your specific scenario. There's no one-size-fits-all solution, but generally it will look something like this:

```js
function findElem ( targetSelector ) {
    // first, we need to query a container (could be table, or a generic item
    //  container). The important thing is, this container must exist on every
    //  page you'll traverse.
    cy.get('.someContainer').then( $container => {
        // synchronously find the target element, however you want. In this
        //  example I use an attribute selector, but you can do whatever you
        //  want.
        if ( $container.find(targetSelector).length ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }).then( found => {
        if ( found ) {

            return cy.log(`found elem "${targetSelector}"`);
        } else {

            // synchronously check if there's a next page/table
            if ( Cypress.$('.nextPageButton').length ) {

                // when know that there is a next page, click it using cypress
                cy.get('.nextPageButton').click();

                // here, assert that next page/table is loaded, possibly by 
                //  asserting that current page/table is removed from DOM

                // then, recurse
                return findElem(targetSelector);
            } else {

                throw new Error(`Couldn't find elem "${targetSelector}" on any page`);
            }
        }
    });
}

it('test', () => {

    findElem(`[data-id="42"]`);
});
```

The crux of the solution is using a combination of commands to query a container, and synchronous inspection (using jQuery or whatever) to find the actual element. Learn more at [Conditional Testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Definition).

For a concrete implementation, you can refer to an [older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040434/927631) I gave to a similar question.